# Office365 Connector custom webhook theme wont change

Tags: json, office365, webhooks, office365connectors

So here's my object that gets sent to my Office365 group:

```
officeObject = {"title":title,
                "text":"Description: " + description,
                "themeColor": "DB4C3F",
                "sections":[
                    {
                        "facts": [
                            {
                                "name":"Assigned to:",
                                "value":"[" + assignedTo + "](" + userUrl + ")"
                            },
                            {
                                "name":"Urgency:",
                                "value":urgency
                            },
                            {
                                "name":"Created on:",
                                "value":created
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "potentialAction": [
                    {
                        "@context": "http://schema.org",
                        "@type": "ViewAction",
                        "name": "View Incident",
                        "target": [
                                url
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                };
```

But here's what the notification looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the color bar above the title is gray, but in my object (line 3) I have "themeColor" set to "DB4C3F" which is HEX for a reddish color. [I pretty much copy and pasted the way the docs said to do it](https://dev.outlook.com/Connectors/GetStarted#color). Anyone know why the color isn't changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your payload is constructed correctly, but there seems to be an issue on the service-side, which we're investigating.

You can follow up via email at connectorbugs@service.microsoft.com, and we'll reach out when the behavior is corrected. Thanks for helping us catch issues during our developer preview!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've already contacted someone and they are keeping me updated.